# Android calendar that pulls data from a server - is there any api's or plgins for

Tags: dynamic, calendar

Android calendar that pulls data from a server - is there any api's or SDK that would help with this.

Basically i have a site and want to add events to the calender in my app.. I haven't got the calender setup but will do..

I would like to dynamically pull data from my website or server..

Does anyone know of any resource or utorials on this that could help me in my quest for solving this..

any help appreciated..

I currently use libGDX framework for my apps if this help at all.

Best

Answer (score 0):

You would need a way to access the database in your server, for example using PHP and MySql:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Then from libgdx a HttpRequest would work. Its the basics at least.

```
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET);
    request.setUrl("http://domainname.com/path/phpfile.php?argument=value");

    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new HttpResponseListener(){
            @Override
            public void handleHttpResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse){
                Gdx.app.log("HttpRequestExample", "response: " + httpResponse.getResultAsString());
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable t){
                Gdx.app.error("HttpRequestExample", "something went wrong", t);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome, Many thanks for this, i will give it a bash and try and get it to work to an extent. Cheers for taking the time to reply in detail.

Comment: No problem. If you consider this as the answer, you should accept it ;) it helps. Good day.